# Margins: box offset from other boxes in row

Tags: html, css

I've built a static dashboard, styled with CSS. It is exactly as I want, but the "Database Searches" box is bumped out of place.  I used CSS to set a bottom margin of 10px for each row, but it looks like this one box is 20px below the one above it. I cannot see anything in my code to explain this. How can I get this one box to play nice, be in line with the "Website Visitors" box next to it?

Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/oyayzze5/

```
.lg {

    width: 700px;
    height: 175px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    position: relative;

}

.med {

    width: 500px;
    height: 175px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sm {

    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block 
}

.left-margin   {

    margin-left: 15px;

}

.row    {

    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h2 {

    text-align: center;
}

p   {

    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.blue   {

        border-color: #41B6E6;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #41B6E6 0%,#41B6E6 45%,white 45%,white 100%);

}

.red    {

    border-color: #ce2029;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ce2029 0%,#ce2029 45%,white 45%,white 100%);

}

.green  {

    border-color: #C4D600;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C4D600 0%,#C4D600 45%,white 45%,white 100%);

}

.orange {

    border-color: #E35205;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E35205 0%,#E35205 45%,white 45%,white 100%);

}
```

Comment: Because your "Database Searches" text is one line, but your "Website Visitors" text is *two*, you'll need to specify that you want them to both anchor to the *top* of the row, instead of the default behavior which is anchoring to the bottom. You can do this by applying `vertical-align: top;` to your `med`, `sm`, and `lg` classes.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct, but I would do it this way:

```
.sm, .med, .lg {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

To elaborate:

Because you've set all these classes to `display: inline-block;`, `vertical-align` is applicable. Since you put a `<br>` in that `h2` in the small red container on that row, and since the default for `vertical-align` is `baseline`, it pushed the center of the row down and threw off the alignment.